# How to filter values by Column Name and then extract the rows that have the same value to another CSV file? Python/Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with 4 columns, the first being "ID NUMBER". I am trying to filter "ID NUMBER" and get the same values bundled together. After that I want to extract each one that have the same values to a different csv file with their respected name.

DataFrame:

```
     ID Number    col2           col3     DATE
0   111            0.5          -0.6    20160104
1   118           -0.1          -0.6    20160104
2   11D            0.3          -1.1    20160104
3   111           -0.7          -0.9    20150102


 ***Output I need:***
 Number ID    col2           col3     DATE
0   111            0.5          -0.6    20160104
1   111           -0.7          -0.9    20150102
```

I have attempted to do something, however I could not find anything about how to filter a columns, and then extract online. Thank you!

Comment: Actually are you just wanting to write each unique ID number to a new csv? if so then `df.groupby('ID Number').apply(lambda x: x.to_csv(str(x.name) + '.csv')` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` with param `keep=False` so it returns `True` for all duplicated rows and mask the df:

```
In [16]:
df[df['ID Number'].duplicated(keep=False)]

Out[16]:
  ID Number  col2  col3      DATE
0       111   0.5  -0.6  20160104
3       111  -0.7  -0.9  20150102
```

For the second part you can do:

```
gp = df[df['ID Number'].duplicated(keep=False)].groupby('ID Number')
gp.apply(lambda x: x.to_csv(str(x.name) + '.csv')
```

**EDIT**

Actually if you're just wanting to write all rows with the same ID number to a named csv then:

```
df.groupby('ID Number').apply(lambda x: x.to_csv(str(x.name) + '.csv'))
```

Should do what you want

Comment: For the second part after EDIT, where can I specify the output path for saving these files?

Comment: Sorry are you after something like `df.groupby('ID Number').apply(lambda x: x.to_csv(r'c:\output\' + str(x.name) + '.csv'))` or you can define an output path variable `path = 'c:/my_output_folder/' and then do `df.groupby('ID Number').apply(lambda x: x.to_csv(path + str(x.name) + '.csv'))`

Comment: Yes, the code you provided worked perfectly! Thank you for the help!